# Understand api curl instruction

Tags: php, curl

Stuck trying to get an api-connection to work. I believe I don't understand the below example request in the api. Especially the last row "grant_type..etc". How is this line to be handled in CURL? As POSTFIELDS? Get an error {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic base64(client_id:client_secret)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

"grant_type=authorization_code&code=<authorization_code>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>"
```

Code so far:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://xxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($clientid.':'.$clientsecret).''
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'redirect_uri' => $redirecturi,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
)); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: probably backend giving you error not curl code itself

Answer (score 0):

https://auth0.com/docs/applications/reference/grant-types-available

Here all  grant type are explained .